# Column is being returned with negative sinal in the end of field in R

Tags: r, sql-server, dplyr, data-manipulation

I'm trying to run this code in SQL Server in R Studio...

```
CASE 
   WHEN COLUMN1 LIKE '%-%' 
      THEN CAST((REPLACE(COLUMN1, '-', '') AS NUMERIC) * -1 
      ELSE COLUMN1 
END VALUE
```

I'm using data table, cause my file there is 2 GB, I've tried to use this:

```
MYDATATABLE[, newfield:=ifelse((COLUMN1 %like% '-'), ***replace '-' for nothing and mutiply this for "-1"***, COLUMN1)]
```

The column is begin returned with the negative sign at the end of value - like this:

```
COLUMN1
--------
 55.400-
 60.440-
 61.280-
136.400-
506.333-
```

Comment: (1) Please format your code properly using the SO editing tools. (2) `MYDATATABLE[...]` does not seem to be valid R code. Where does the infix operator `%like$` come from? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50709208/edit) your question to include some sample data and your expected output; it's not clear to me what you're trying to do. What is a "negative sinal"? Do you mean signal? Sign?

Comment: Sorry, I not managed to explain very well what I really want to do, the answer of Prem works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly then you can try two step process.

Instead of slow performing `ifelse` you could first create a new column `new_col` if `col1` has `-` by assigning the negative of `col1`'s numeric value after removing `-` from `col1`. Then replace `NA` value in `new_col` with numeric value of `col1`.

```r
library(data.table)

DT[grepl("-", col1), 
   new_col := - as.numeric(gsub("-", "", col1))][is.na(new_col), new_col := as.numeric(col1)]
```

which gives

```
> DT
    col1 id new_col
1:  -123  1    -123
2: 1233-  2   -1233
3:    45  3      45
```

**Sample data:**

```
DT <- data.table(col1 = c("-123","1233-", "45"),
                 id = c(1,2,3))
#    col1 id
#1:  -123  1
#2: 1233-  2
#3:    45  3
```

Comment: Thanks Prem! Great Solution!